# Only 1 of 10 ImageViews displaying - Android

Tags: java, android, imageview

One part of my code is a `LinearLayout` within a `ScrollView`.  The `ScrollView` has 10 rows with 4 columns in each row.  The first column is a small `ImageView` (either a red 'x' or green check mark).  From the picture below, only the first `ImageView` is displaying for some reason.  I want one to display for each row in the first column.

Here is the XML code:

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="65"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" > 

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"  /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q1Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp" /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q2Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>

        <View 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"       
            android:background="#C2BEBF" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Image"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp" />

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Question"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="48"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  />  

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Answer"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="27"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 

                <TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/q3Verse"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_weight="25"
                    android:paddingBottom="6dp"
                    android:paddingTop="6dp"  /> 
            </LinearLayout>
```

Java code

```
ImageView q1Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q1Image);
        q1Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q2Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q2Image);
        q2Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q3Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q3Image);
        q3Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q4Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q4Image);
        q4Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q5Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q5Image);
        q5Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q6Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q6Image);
        q6Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q7Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q7Image);
        q7Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q8Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q8Image);
        q8Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q9Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q9Image);
        q9Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        ImageView q10Image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.q10Image);
        q10Image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);

        ArrayList<ImageView> ivArray = new ArrayList<ImageView>(10);
        ivArray.add(q1Image);
        ivArray.add(q2Image);
        ivArray.add(q3Image);
        ivArray.add(q4Image);
        ivArray.add(q5Image);
        ivArray.add(q6Image);
        ivArray.add(q7Image);
        ivArray.add(q8Image);
        ivArray.add(q9Image);
        ivArray.add(q10Image);
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            if(qs.get(i).getSelectedAnswer() == qs.get(i).getCorrectAnswer()) {
                ivArray.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_check_mark);
            } else {
                ivArray.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_x);
            }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be implementing a ListView and an Adapter. As you can see, the code to manage manually adding every row to your ScrollView and manually acquiring every ImageView reference is painful.

Please see [Building Layouts with an Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Please post any questions you have and I would be happy to expand my answer.

Now, to more directly answer your question...

Your for loop only accesses index 0. Try this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ivArray.size(); i++)
```

Comment: ah, I changed that loop to 1 for testing and forgot to change it back after testing was done.  Thank you for pointing it out.  As for the ````Adapter````, let me research your link and Google and see if I should implement that.  You are right, it is a pain to change everything in the ````ScrollView````.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the bug in your Java code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
     if(qs.get(i).getSelectedAnswer() == qs.get(i).getCorrectAnswer()) {
         vArray.get(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.green_check_mark);
      } 
// ....
```

Your loop stops at 1 `(i < 1)`.  Try changing it to `(i < 10)` and see if it gets better.

Comment: Rather than choose an arbitrary number why not use the size of the List?

Comment: Agreed - I chose to focus on the immediate problem, rather than criticize the OP's coding style.  If I were venturing down that route, I'd suggest he/she replace all the nested LinearLayouts with a ListView and Adapter-based approach.

Comment: Ah, I changed that loop to 1 for testing purposes and forgot to change it back when I was done testing.  Thank you for pointing that out.  Aso for ````ListView```` and ````Adapter````, I will have to look into that.  I have been suggested to try that a number of times now but just never have.

Comment: WindyB and I both concur - you should check out the link to the Adapter tutorial.  Adapters allow you to separate the data from the layout, so you can use a data set (quiz questions in your case) of any size. You store the data elsewhere (such as a SQLite database), update the data at run time, and use the same layout with any data set without changing your code.  They are a much more flexible approach overall.